# Where is the "Access Software" link in AWS Marketplace for SAS University Edition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sas, aws-marketplace

I'm following the instructions below but getting stuck:

http://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/docs/en/SASUniversityEditionQuickStartAWS.pdf

I've deployed SAS University Edition on AWS from the AWS Marketplace with 1-click install.  The EC2 instance has been online for over an hour, and I can see "SAS University Edition" in the "Your Software Subscriptions" page.

However, the guide then says "Click the Access Software link for the SAS University Edition instance".  I can't see this "Access Software" link on the "Your Software Subscriptions" page.

Here is what I see:

[image: Screenshot of SAS University Edition in my "Your Software Subscriptions" page]

I was going to connect direct to the IP of the EC2 instance but it doesn't have a Public IP assigned.

[image: EC2 instance screenshot]

I have setup inbound rules for the EC2 instance for SSH, HTTP and HTTPS:

[image]

Does anyone know why it's missing and what I can do to fix it or get around it?

Comment: Looking some more, I found this article: "http://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/AWS_runvApp.htm" and my screen looks different to the screenshot in this.

Comment: I tried to login to the EC2 instance with the Java SSH client but it won't let me login.  MindTerm loads in Java but then I get this error after a minute or so: "Error connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, reason:
-> Server closed connection before sending identification".  (It does display the IP, but I masked it).

Comment: If you don't get a solution here, communities.sas.com is monitored by SAS Staff who can help with issues. Or you can email support@sas.com. SAS is pretty good at supporting issues on SAS UE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: when doing set up, choose 1-click or automatic. Don't do a manual set up.

Then, once its in your subscription page, go to the EC2 instance page in AWS (aws.amazon.com). It will show your micro instance running in a locale that you selected. In addition at the bottom you'll find two fields called PUBLIC DNS and your Instance ID.

Copy and paste the the PUBLIC DNS into your browser and it will launch SAS. Then enter sasdemo as your ID and the Instance ID as your password.

Comment: Thanks, but do you mean Public IP?  If you do, it doesn't have one assigned (had thought of that).  I tried to assign an Elastic IP but it doesn't have an internet gateway.

Comment: It turned out that my VPC didn't have an assigned Internet Gateway.  I've created the Internet Gateway and assigned an Elastic IP now.  The EC2 instance has a Public IP now, but I can't seem to access it in any way.  I can't ping it or SSH, and I can't connect to it from the web browser with either HTTP or HTTPS using the Public IP.

Comment: I added a comment to answer. Choose the 1-click set rather than manual and then go to through steps I mentioned. I tested from start to finish and got it set up in under 10 mins. I'll see about adding screenshots later.

Comment: Thanks.  I did do that but I will start again and see if things improve.

Comment: Thanks.  I re-ran the 1-click in the default VPC instead of creating my own new VPC, and that worked (though I still can't see the proper options in the Marketplace, but at least it now has a Public DNS and Public IP and I can connect to it). I suspect it had something to do with my new VPC not being set to create Public addresses by default.

Comment: Have you guys figured out a way to upload data from an S3 bucket to SAS Studio ?? Using Proc S3 is returning Bad Request error and I've read it needs a hot fix but I dont know if we can implement hot fixes using AMI's like this...

Comment: S3 was previously blocked because of an HTTPS restriction. That restriction no longer exists so in theory you should be able to connect fine. Unfortunately I know nothing about using it via AWS. I would suggest posting your own question and include your code/log.